# Why doesn't this reinterpret_cast compile?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I understand that `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous, I'm just doing this to test it. I have the following code:

```
int x = 0;
double y = reinterpret_cast<double>(x);
```

When I try to compile the program, it gives me an error saying

> invalid cast from type 'float' to type 'double

What's going on? I thought `reinterpret_cast` was the rogue cast that you could use to convert apples to submarines, why won't this simple cast compile?

Comment: I haven't ever tried this in C++, so I am only guessing.  Does it work if you cast to float?  Could it not like that the two types have a different bit length?

Comment: "`reinterpret_cast<double>(x)`" What did you _expected_ this expression to do?

Comment: int is 32 bits. double is 64 bits. That could be the issue. Can you check?

Comment: Are you sure the compiler complains about `float`? There's no `float` in your code snippet.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Perhaps a better way of thinking of `reinterpret_cast` is the rouge operator that can "convert" *pointers* to apples as *pointers* to submarines.

By assigning y to the value returned by the cast you're not really casting the value `x`, you're converting it.  That is, `y` doesn't point to `x` and pretend that it points to a float.  Conversion constructs a new value of type `float` and assigns it the value from `x`.  There are several ways to do this conversion in C++, among them:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    float f = static_cast<float>(x);
    float f2 = (float)x;
    float f3 = float(x);
    float f4 = x;
    return 0;
}
```

The only real difference being the last one (an implicit conversion) will generate a compiler diagnostic on higher warning levels.  But they all do functionally the same thing -- and in many case *actually* the same thing, as in the same machine code.

Now if you really do want to pretend that `x` is a float, then you really do want to cast `x`, by doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    float* pf = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x);
    (*pf)++;
    cout << *pf;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see how dangerous this is.  In fact, the output when I run this on my machine is `1`, which is decidedly not 42+1.

Comment: will (float)x return 42 or some binary representation of some unrelated double. I think this guy means reinterpret and that's what he wants.

Comment: `(float)x` will perform a conversion, not a cast.

Comment: Your code below is strict aliasing violation and therefore has an undefined behavior.

Comment: When I do this sort of thing in low-level code, frequently it's to display the bits without ANY sort of conversion applied (except to printable hex).  E.g. when (de-)serializing data structures swapped with a microcontroller.  Think "debugger".

Comment: @JohnDibling A cast *is* an explicit conversion, by definition.

Answer (score 62):

In C++ `reinterpret_cast` can only perform a specific set of conversions, explicitly listed in the language specification. In short, `reinterpret_cast` can only perform pointer-to-pointer conversions and reference-to-reference conversions (plus pointer-to-integer and integer-to-pointer conversions). This is consistent with the intent expressed in the very name of the cast: it is intended to be used for pointer/reference reinterpretation.

What you are trying to do is not reinterpretation. If you want to reinterpret an `int` as a `double` you'd have to convert it to a reference type

```
double y = reinterpret_cast<double&>(x);
```

although the equivalent pointer-based reinterpretation is probably more explicit

```
double y = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&x); // same as above
```

Note though, that while `reinterpret_cast` can convert the reference/pointer types, the actual attempt to read the data through the resultant reference/pointer produces undefined behavior.

And in any case this, of course, can't make much sense on a platform with `int` and `double` of different size (since in case of larger `double` you will read beyond the memory occupied by `x`).

So, in the end it all boils down to what you were trying to achieve. Memory reinterpretation? See above. Some kind of more meaningful `int` to `double` conversion? If so, `reinterpret_cast` won't help you here.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast can only perform pointer-to-pointer conversions and reference-to-reference conversions (plus pointer-to-integer and integer-to-pointer conversions)` this flattened the question and could be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 16):

If you are trying to convert the bits of your `int` to a the representation of a `double`, you need to cast the *address* not the value.  You must also make sure the sizes match:

```
uint64_t x = 0x4045000000000000;
double y = *reinterpret_cast<double *>(&x);
```

Answer (score 12):

reinterpret_cast is not a general cast.  According to the C++03 spec section 5.2.10.1:

> Conversions that can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast are listed below. No other conversion can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast.

And there is nothing listed that describes converting between integral and floating point types (or between integral types, even this is illegal `reinterpret_cast<long>(int(3));`)

Answer (score 7):

The compiler rejects what you wrote as nonsense because `int` and `double` may be objects with different sizes. You could achieve the same effect this way, although it is certainly dangerous:

```
int x = 0;
double y = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&x);
```

This is potentially dangerous because if `x` and `y` are diffrent sizes (let's say `int` is four bytes and `double` is eight bytes) then when you dereference the eight bytes of memory at `&x` to fill in `y` you will access four bytes of `x` and four bytes of ... whatever comes next in memory (possibly the start of `y`, or garbage, or something else entirely.)

If you want to convert a integer to a double, use a `static_cast` and it will perform conversion.

If you want to access the bit-pattern of `x`, cast to some convenient pointer type (say, `byte*`) and access up to `sizeof(int) / sizeof(byte)`:

```
byte* p = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&x);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
  // do something with p[i]
}
```

Comment: Not the reason why the compiler rejects it, but the discussion on type sizes is valuable.

Answer (score 5):

Reinterpret cast allows you to reinterpret a block of memory as a different type. This has to be performed on pointers *or references*:

```
int x = 1;
float & f = reinterpret_cast<float&>(x);
assert( static_cast<float>(x) != f );   // !!
```

The other thing is that it is in fact a quite dangerous cast, not only due to strange values coming out as results, or the assert above not failing, but because if the types are of different sizes, and you reinterpret from 'source' to 'destination' types, any operation on the reinterpreted reference/pointer will access `sizeof(destination)` bytes. If `sizeof(destination)>sizeof(source)` then that will step beyond the actual variable memory, potentially killing your application or overwritting other variables other than the source or destination:

```
struct test {
   int x;
   int y;
};
test t = { 10, 20 };
double & d = reinterpret_cast<double&>( t.x );
d = 1.0/3.0;
assert( t.x != 10 ); // most probably at least.
assert( t.y != 20 );
```

Answer (score 3):

The reinterpret approach led me down a strange path with inconsistent results. In the end I found it much better to memcpy like this!

```
double source = 0.0;
uint64_t dest;
memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting.  Maybe it's doing an implicit conversion from int to float before it attempts the cast to double.  int and float types tend to be the same size in bytes (depending on your system of course).

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` is best used for pointers.   So a pointer to one object can be turned into a "submarine".

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b(VS.80).aspx):

> The reinterpret_cast operator can be
>   used for conversions such as char* to
>   int*, or One_class* to
>   Unrelated_class*, which are inherently
>   unsafe.
>
> The result of a reinterpret_cast
>   cannot safely be used for anything
>   other than being cast back to its
>   original type. Other uses are, at
>   best, nonportable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union.  It is the least error-prone way to memory map between an integer and a floating point type.  Reinterpreting a pointer will cause aliasing warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union { uint32_t i; float f; } v;  // avoid aliasing rules trouble
    v.i = 42;
    printf("int 42 is float %f\n", v.f);
    v.f = 42.0;
    printf("float 42 is int 0x%08x\n", v.i);
}
```

Comment: No, using an union this way is implementation-specific and therefore not the least error-prone way (see [Purpose of Unions in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c)) For example: If `i` is 32 bits and `f` is 64 bits, does `i` correspond to the upper or lower 32 bits of `f`?

Comment: If the sizes mismatch, reinterpreting pointers leads to even bigger problems, but your link is very good.  I concede that unions are not well grounded for this purpose, and likely to have portability problems, but those are inherent in the task.

Comment: This approach doesn't perform any conversion. It doesn't achieve what the question is asking.

Comment: I see this answer as useful because it doesn't have the chance of accidentally overwriting other important data if you DO mess up when using `reinterpret_cast`. However, note that a `union`ed program may be slightly more difficult to debug as a result because you have generally better behavior that doesn't overwrite data it never should've had access to. @MrRickDean's way should prevent segfaults (accessing data outside program memory) and unexpected variable-data overwrites (assuming you use `union` correctly...), but it won't prevent any logical/bad-programmer-brain errors.

Answer (score -1):

Casting an int to a double doesn't require a cast.  The compiler will perform the assignment implicitly.

The reinterpret_cast is used with pointers and references, e.g., casting an `int *` to a `double *`.