# How do I receive data sent by sigqueue() syscall

Tags: c, signals, ipc, sigqueue

I have 2 process sigserver and sigclient. sigserver waits for a signal to come and sigclient sends data (int+char) to sigserver.

**sigserver.c**

```
void sighand(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *extra)
{
       void *ptr_val = info->si_value.sival_ptr;
       int int_val = info->si_value.sival_int;
       printf("Signal: %d, value: [%d] %s\n", signo, int_val, (char*)ptr_val);
}

int main()
{
        struct sigaction action;

        action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        action.sa_sigaction = &sighand;

        if (sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, NULL) == -1) {
                perror("sigusr: sigaction");
                return 0;
        }

        printf("Signal handler installed, waiting for signal\n");

        while(1) {sleep(2);}

        return 0;
}
```

**sigclient.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        union sigval value;
        int pid = atoi(argv[1]);

        value.sival_int = atoi(argv[2]);
        value.sival_ptr = (void*) strdup(argv[3]);
        if(sigqueue(pid, SIGUSR2, value) == 0) {
                printf("signal sent successfully!!\n");
        } else {
                perror("SIGSENT-ERROR:");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

now when I run client with below command  ./client server_pid 15 teststring

server generates core dump.

My question is, how can a process read string sent by another process(not child).

Comment: Be careful: `sigval` is a `union`, which means that you can either set `sival_int` or `sival_ptr`, but not both! See [Purpose of Unions in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c/2313676) and [Unions in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The address which is sent from one process to the other via the value of `sival_ptr` is not valid in the receiving process, as the two processes do **not** share the same address space.

Due to this undefined behaviour is invoked on the receiver side when accessing `sival_ptr`.

The logic used in the example shown would only work if receiver and sender were the same  process and thus use the same address space.

Note: In contrast to `sival_ptr` the value of `sival_int` could be used on the receiver side, as its value **is** the data.

---

To send data more complex  than a single integer from one process to another use different IPC mechanic, like shared memory, sockets, pipes, ...

Comment: thts wt I was thinking abt, but not sure, thnx for the confirmation.