# Limiting structures size by use of :

Tags: c++

Why this piece of code is needed ?

```
typedef struct corr_id_{
    unsigned int  size:8;       
    unsigned int  valueType:8;  
    unsigned int  classId:8;   
    unsigned int  reserved:8;    

} CorrId;
```

I did some investigation around it and found that this way we are limiting the memory consumption to just what we need.
For E.g.

```
typedef struct corr_id_new{
    unsigned int  size;       
    unsigned int  valueType;  
    unsigned int  classId;   
    unsigned int  reserved;   

} CorrId_NEW;

typedef struct corr_id_{
    unsigned int  size:8;       
    unsigned int  valueType:8;  
    unsigned int  classId:8;   
    unsigned int  reserved:8;   

} CorrId;

int main(){
CorrId_NEW Obj1;
CorrId     Obj2;

std::cout<<sizeof(Obj1)<<endl;
std::cout<<sizeof(Obj2)<<endl;
}
```

Output:-

```
16
4
```

I want to understand the real use case of such scenarios? why can't we declare the struct something like this,

```
typedef struct corr_id_new{
    unsigned _int8  size;       
    unsigned _int8  valueType;  
    unsigned _int8  classId;   
    unsigned _int8  reserved;   

} CorrId_NEW;
```

Does this has something to do with compiler optimizations? Or, what are the benefits of declaring the structure that way?

Comment: actually you should combine the two approaches... or use `pack`/`packed`

Comment: Are you sure the output is `4 16`, not `16 4`?

Comment: Thanks. made those changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Unions in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c)

Comment: You assumed the original programmer knew what he was doing.  That's not always a correct assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see a simple scenario,

```
typedef struct student{
    unsigned int  age:8; // max 8-bits is enough to store a students's age 255 years
    unsigned int  roll_no:16;  //max roll_no can be 2^16, which long enough
    unsigned int  classId:4;   //class ID can be 4-bits long (0-15), as per need.
    unsigned int  reserved:4;  // reserved

};
```

Above case all work is done in 32-bits only.

But if you use just a integer it would have taken 4*32 bits.

If we take age as 32-bit integer, It can store in range of 0 to 2^32. But don't forget a normal person's age is just max 100 or 140 or 150 (even somebody studying in this age also), which needs max 8-bits to store, So why to waste remaining 24-bits.

Comment: +20   for your answer..:)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to understand the real use case of such scenarios?

For example, structure of status register of some CPU may look like this:

[image]

In order to represent it via structure, you could use **bitfield**:

```
struct CSR
{
    unsigned N: 1;
    unsigned Z: 1;
    unsigned C: 1;
    unsigned V: 1;
    unsigned  : 20;
    unsigned I: 1;
    unsigned  : 2;
    unsigned M: 5;
};
```

You can see here that fields are not multiplies of 8, so you can't use `int8_t`, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's often used with `pragma pack` to create bitfields with labels, e.g.:

```
#pragma pack(0)

struct eg {
    unsigned int one : 4;
    unsigned int two : 8;
    unsigned int three : 16
};
```

Can be cast for whatever purpose to an `int32_t`, and vice versa.  This might be useful when reading serialized data that follows a (language agnostic) protocol -- you extract an int and cast it to a `struct eg` to match the fields and field sizes defined in the protocol.  You could also skip the conversion and just read an int sized chunk into such a struct, point being that the bitfield sizes match the protocol field sizes.  This is extremely common in network programming -- if you want to send a packet following the protocol, you just populate your struct, serialize, and transmit.

*Note that `pragma pack` is not standard C but it is recognized by various common compilers.*  Without pragma pack, however, the compiler is free to place padding between fields, reducing the use value for the purposes described above.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the last structure definition with `unsigned _int8` is almost equivalent to the definition using `:8`. Almost, because byte order can make a difference here, so you might find that the memory layout is reversed in the two cases.

The main purpose of the `:8` notation is to allow the use of fractional bytes, as in

```
struct foo {
    uint32_t a:1;
    uint32_t b:2;
    uint32_t c:3;
    uint32_t d:4;
    uint32_t e:5;
    uint32_t f:6;
    uint32_t g:7;
    uint32_t h:4;
}
```

To minimize padding, I strongly suggest to learn the padding rules yourself, they are not hard to grasp. If you do, you can know that your version with `unsigned _int8` does not add *any* padding. Or, if you don't feel like learning those rules, just use `__attribute__((__packed__))` on your struct, but that may introduce a severe performance penalty.