# C++ floating point representation

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am trying to create a `float` from a hexadecimal representation I got from [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). For the representation of `32.50002`, the site shows the IEEE 754 hexadecimal representation as `0x42020005`.

In my code, I have this: `float f = 0x42020005;`. However, when I print the value, I get `1.10E+9` instead of `32.50002`. Why is this?

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: `0x42020005` is 1107427333, just sayin’.

Comment: @Gareth - C++ is not IEEE.  That 0x42020005 is an integer.  Your code is no different than if I did this:
`float f = 1107427333;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign a value to a `float` variable via `=`, you don’t assign its internal representation, you assign its value. 0x42020005 in decimal is 1107427333, and that’s the value you are assigning.

The underlying representation of a `float` cannot be retrieved in a platform independent way. However, making some assumptions (namely, that the `float` is in fact using IEEE 754 format), we can trick a bit:

```
float f;
uint32_t rep = 0x42020005;
std::memcpy(&f, &rep, sizeof f);
```

Will give the desired result.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `intptr_t` is a type with the width of a pointer. That’s not at all what we want – we want a 32-bit type, independent of machine. `intptr_t`, on the other hand, can be a different size.

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is formally undefined behavior.  The _intent_ of the standard is clearly that an implementation define it to give the expected results, but IIRC, g++ doesn't.  (If you write something like `float f = 0.0; *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f) = 0x42020005; std::cout << f;`, you might end up outputting 0.)  The only way that is formally defined is using `memcpy`.  (But I tend to use `reinterpret_cast` and/or `union` myself, depending on the compiler I'm targetting.)

Comment: @Kanze can you point at the section in standard where it says this?

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah, good catch. Personally I would only use `reinterpret_cast` when I can alias via `[unsigned] char*`, i.e. preserving strict aliasing (and yes, I could do that here, but it’s even more code). I’ve changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`0x42020005` actually is `int` value of 1107427333.

You can try out this code. Should work... Use union:

```
union IntFloat {
  uint32_t i;
  float f;
};
```

and call it when you need to convert the value.

```
union IntFloat val;
val.i = 0x42020005;
printf("%f\n", val.f);
```

Comment: Cool, I've never had much use for union before. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is technically undefined behavior (although I don't know of a compiler where it won't work).

Comment: @James Are you confident that this will never break with optimisations turned on? After all, optimisers trace reads and writes and eliminate unused code paths – and this *does* come into conflict with strict aliasing violations. Are exceptions for unions built in?

Comment: @JamesKanze, I actually learn it from someone and have been using it since. I have tried it on Visual Studio 2008 to 2012, with no problem so far, of course, there are many methods like Konrad's method, a more standard approach actually.

Comment: Them purpose of my method is to avoid assumption of big or little endian and to avoid breaking any aliasing rule.

Comment: For more information on unions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c

Comment: @KonradRudolph G++ guarantees it explicitly.  It will generally work _if_ all of the accesses to `union` are through the union members.  If you do something like `float* pf = *val.f;`, and then access through `*pf`, it generally won't work.  (This is probably why g++ chose to support this path, rather than the `reinterpret_cast`; it's rather simple to determine whether you're accessing through the `union`, without looking further, and avoid the dangerous optimizations.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph FWIW, however: although I think Microsoft supports it now, under roughly the same conditions as g++, some very, very early Microsoft C compilers didn't.

Answer (score 1):

`0x42020005` is an `int` with value of 1107427333.

`float f = 0x42020005;` is equal with
`float f = 1107427333;`

Comment: Edit: sorry, I used std::oct and the value was wrong.