# flags as union of bitset and uint64_t

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

Recently learned about unions in c++ and I come up with this in order to handle multiple flags represented by a single uint64_t,etc

```
union myflags_t
{
  uint64_t var;
  std::bitset<64> bits;

  myflags_t() { }
};
```

The alternative way I was using before was [bit operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/3024116), specifically *setting a bit* and *changing the nth bit to x*.

Instead I can use

```
myflags_t flags;
flags.var = 0;
flags.bits[nth bit] = ...
```

My question is **Which is faster the union or bit operations?**

Also if it is faster to use the union why haven't I come across this before?

Edit:
Removed memset (misunderstood and did not need it)
The reason I'm using union is because later in the code I need to pass the variable as uint64_t
Edit 2:
Read over comments and I'm convinced that I'm using union wrong. The code creates undefined behaviour since unions are not meant for type punning. Going to close the question.

Comment: "if it is faster to use the union why haven't I come across this before?" - because it's relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What should I be using instead of memset?

Comment: If you're going to use the std, use the std. In this case, bits.reset() will reset everything stored in bits to 0. Adding the union in this example only makes things less clear. Not an answer to your question, but I wasn't trying for one.

Comment: @DisplayName101: At the very least, switch to `std::fill`. In industry I've seen terrible bugs go undiagnosed for years when an array was swapped for a map (yeah) and the lack of useful type safety on `memset` meant the entire container was being silently ruined (causing UB).

Comment: @Aumnayan the reason I'm using union is because I have to send to send it as a uint64_t later, not because it allows to me set it to 0 quickly.

Comment: @DisplayName101: You're abusing `union` to perform invalid type punning. This is not what `union` is for. It's a common misconception.

Comment: @DisplayName101: look up bitfields then. This isn't a portable solution as it's behavior is determined by the compiler and not a standard, but if that's not a problem for you it will provide the clean interface you're looking for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read over [union](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2313676/3024116) and I understand that they were created for  saving memory, but from what I understood from the link since C99 using union for type punning is ok

Comment: @Aumnayan: It's UB so the behaviour can vary on the same compiler between compilation runs or even between execution runs. _Anything_ can happen. It'll never not be a problem for you.

Comment: @DisplayName101: Either the link is wrong or you understood it incorrectly (though there is a subset of cases in which it's okay). And C++ is not C99.

Comment: @DisplayName101 As others have said, `union` is not designed to flip bits between types. It is designed to save space when you only need one of the types. If you need to use a `uint32_t` at some point, you should probably just use a `uint32_t` from the beginning and stick with it. You could also just use a `bitset` and convert it to a `uint32_t` later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ....

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : That not an all inclusive answer, thought it might be accurate for your working environment. For example: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Fields defines how bit fields are used in GNU gcc/g++. In that environment bitfields operate in a very precise way.

Comment: Just use `std::bitset`. It has `to_ulong()` and `to_ullong()`.

Comment: @Aumnayan: We're talking about how `union` works, not how bitfields work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flip the nth bit you can do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>

int main( void )
{
  uint64_t u64 = 1024;
  std::bitset <64> b64;

  b64 = u64;
  b64.flip(0);

  u64 = b64.to_ulong();

  std::cout << u64 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```