# Unions not working properly

Tags: c++, data-structures, structure, storage, unions

This is my code. It Works fine with C but it is behaving like structures in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    union myunion
    {
        int B;
        double PI;
    };

    union myunion numbers;
    numbers.PI = 3.14;
    numbers.B = 12; 

    /* now storage of PI should be over-written */

    cout<<numbers.PI<<endl;
    cout<<numbers.B<<endl;

    /* Output is  3.14 */
    /*            12   */
    /* Why it is behaving like Structures ? */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is undefined behavior in either C or C++.

Comment: Reading a different member of a union from the last one written is UB in most cases. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c/2313676#2313676

Comment: It appears I was mistaken about C. It's undefined in C++, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848/10077.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have explained to you why this is undefined behaviour - and why to never do this - but if you're still curious as to what's happening here: read on.

With the right compiler, on the right platform, during the right phase of the moon, the following happens.

1. `sizeof(double)` == 8
2. Setting `numbers.PI` to 3.14 sets 8 bytes in memory to `1f 85 eb 51 b8 1e 09 40` and displays `numbers {B=1374389535 PI=3.1400000000000001}` in the watch window
3. `sizeof(int)` == 4
4. So - when you set `numbers.B` to 12, *only the first four bytes* of that memory are changed. `numbers` is now stored as `0c 00 00 00 b8 1e 09 40` (the 0c000000 is 12 on my Intel processor) and the b81e09f0 are what was left behind of PI.
5. As it happens, Intel, the IEEE and the compiler union packing order have led to the 12 trashing only the least significant bits of PI's mantissa (without disturbing its exponent).
6. `numbers` is now shown in the watch window as `numbers {B=12 PI=3.1399993896484428}`

So, `numbers.PI` *has been modified*! It was 3.1400000000000001, and now it is 3.1399993896484428. But when you stream it to `cout` its new value gets rounded to 3.14 for display purposes, hiding the fact that its value has changed.

**But remember** - accessing any member of a union other than the one most recently set is *still* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Commenters have mentioned, and [Cppreference on `union` states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

Which is why your program is behaving as such: it's undefined behaviour. It could show the previous value, or crash, or anything in between.

```
numbers.PI = 3.14;
numbers.B = 12; 

cout<<numbers.PI<<endl; // undefined behaviour
```

Comment: So should one avoid using unions in C++ ? Because in C++ there behavior is UNDEFINED ? And also output is both the values as if DIFFERENT MEMORIES are used to store them ( but unions store it's members in a single memory locations )

Comment: @user7402737 You should not avoid using unions but  you should not access the the member of union which was not most recently written.