# Multiplication operator not returning value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a Matrix3 class which has an overloaded * operator so i should be able to go:

```
Matrix3 m1, m2, m3
m2.setRotateX(3.98f); //values are not important just setting a value.
m3.setRotateZ(9.62f);

m1 = m2 * m3
```

Expected result: 
m1 is assigned the result of m2 * m3 calculation. Instead it appears to be still assigned whatever was in memory when it was created.

I have looked at it in the debugger and the result code at the end of the operator * method is assigned to the correct values but it never is assigned for some reason.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 (I tried updating to latest version) and currently running with the Debug x86 profile.

I should also point out I am not using a pre-made maths library because this is part of an assignment.

Here is the full code for the class:
matrix3.h

```
#pragma once
#include "vector3.h"

class Matrix3
{
public:
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            Vector3 xAxis;
            Vector3 yAxis;
            union {

                Vector3 zAxis;
                Vector3 translation;
            };
        };
        Vector3 axis[3];
        float data[3][3];
    };
    static const Matrix3 identity;

    Matrix3(Vector3 x, Vector3 y, Vector3 z) : xAxis{ x }, yAxis{ y }, zAxis{ z } { }
    Matrix3(float f1, float f2, float f3, float f4, float f5, float f6, float f7, float f8, float f9) : data{ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9 } {}
    Matrix3() : Matrix3{ identity } {}

    Matrix3(const Matrix3 &other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++)
            axis[i] = other.axis[i];
    }




    Matrix3& operator= (const Matrix3& other);

    Vector3& operator[] (int index);
    const Vector3& operator[] (int index) const;
    Matrix3 operator * (const Matrix3& other) const;
    Vector3 operator * (const Vector3& v) const;

    Matrix3 operator + (const Matrix3& other) const;
    Matrix3 operator - (const Matrix3& other) const;
    operator float*() { return reinterpret_cast<float*>(data); }

    Matrix3 transpose() const;

    void setScaled(float x, float y, float z);
    void setScaled(const Vector3& v);
    void scale(float x, float y, float z);
    void scale(const Vector3 v);

    void setRotateX(float radians);
    void setRotateY(float radians);
    void setRotateZ(float radians);

    void rotateX(float radians);
    void rotateY(float radians);
    void rotateZ(float radians);

    void setEuler(float pitch, float yaw, float roll);


    operator std::string() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Matrix3& matrix);
};
```

matrix3.cpp

```
#include "Matrix3.h"

const Matrix3 Matrix3::identity = Matrix3({ 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 });
static const int MATRIX_DIMS = 3;


Vector3& Matrix3::operator[] (int index)
{
    return axis[index];
}

const Vector3& Matrix3::operator[] (int index) const
{
    return axis[index];
}


Matrix3& Matrix3::operator=(const Matrix3& other)
{
    xAxis = other.xAxis;
    yAxis = other.yAxis;
    zAxis = other.zAxis;

    return *this;
}

Matrix3 Matrix3::operator * (const Matrix3& other) const
{
    Matrix3 result;

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            result.data[c][r] = data[0][r] * other.data[c][0] +
            data[1][r] * other.data[c][1] +
            data[2][r] * other.data[c][2];

    return result;
}

Vector3 Matrix3::operator * (const Vector3& v) const
{
    Vector3 result;

    for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        result[r] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_DIMS; ++i)
            result[r] += data[i][r] * v[i];
    }

    return result;
}

Matrix3 Matrix3::operator+(const Matrix3& other) const
{
    Matrix3 result;

    for (int x = 0; x < MATRIX_DIMS; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < MATRIX_DIMS; y++)
            result[x][y] = data[x][y] + other[x][y];

    return result;
}

Matrix3 Matrix3::operator-(const Matrix3& other) const
{
    Matrix3 result;

    for (int x = 0; x < MATRIX_DIMS; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < MATRIX_DIMS; y++)
            result[x][y] = data[x][y] - other[x][y];

    return result;
}

Matrix3 Matrix3::transpose() const
{
    Matrix3 result;

    for (int r = 0; r < MATRIX_DIMS; ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c < MATRIX_DIMS; ++c)
            result.data[r][c] = data[c][r];

    return result;
}

void Matrix3::setScaled(const Vector3& v)
{
    // set scale of each axis
    xAxis = { v.x, 0, 0 };
    yAxis = { 0, v.y, 0 };
    zAxis = { 0, 0, v.z };
}

void Matrix3::setScaled(float x, float y, float z)
{
    // set scale of each axis
    xAxis = { x, 0, 0 };
    yAxis = { 0, y, 0 };
    zAxis = { 0, 0, z };
}

void Matrix3::scale(const Vector3 v)
{
    Matrix3 m;
    m.setScaled(v.x, v.y, v.z);

    *this = *this * m;
}

void Matrix3::scale(float x, float y, float z)
{
    Matrix3 m;
    m.setScaled(x, y, z);

    *this = *this * m;
}

void Matrix3::rotateX(float radians)
{
    Matrix3 m;
    m.setRotateX(radians);

    *this = *this * m;
}

void Matrix3::rotateY(float radians)
{
    Matrix3 m;
    m.setRotateY(radians);

    *this = *this * m;
}

void Matrix3::rotateZ(float radians)
{
    Matrix3 m;
    m.setRotateZ(radians);

    *this = *this * m;
}

void Matrix3::setRotateX(float radians)
{
    xAxis = { 1, 0, 0 };
    yAxis = { 0, cosf(radians), sinf(radians) };
    zAxis = { 0, -sinf(radians), cosf(radians) };
}

void Matrix3::setRotateY(float radians)
{
    xAxis = { cosf(radians), 0, -sinf(radians) };
    yAxis = { 0, 1, 0 };
    zAxis = { sinf(radians), 0, cosf(radians) };
}

void Matrix3::setRotateZ(float radians)
{
    xAxis = { cosf(radians), sinf(radians), 0 };
    yAxis = { -sinf(radians), cosf(radians), 0 };
    zAxis = { 0, 0, 1 };
}

void Matrix3::setEuler(float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
{
    Matrix3 x, y, z;
    x.setRotateX(pitch);
    y.setRotateY(yaw);
    z.setRotateZ(roll);

    *this = z * y * x;
}


Matrix3::operator std::string() const
{
    std::string result = "";

    for (int r = 0; r < MATRIX_DIMS; ++r)
    {
        result += "{";
        for (int c = 0; c < MATRIX_DIMS; ++c)
        {
            result += std::to_string(data[r][c]);

            if (r != MATRIX_DIMS - 1 || c != MATRIX_DIMS - 1)
                result += ",";
        }
        result += "}";
    }

    return result;

}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Matrix3& matrix)
{
    os << static_cast<std::string>(matrix);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `union` to map data like that. Using any `union` member that was not the last to be assigned to is undefined behavior.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Is it because I am using both floats and Vector3 objects or is it the use of a union inside a union?

Comment: That solved the problem thank you so much, been bashing my head against a wall for the last few hours on that one :). You should post that as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: This is a _lot_ of code. Please be more minimal (without sacrificing correctness or reproducibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supplied code exhibits undefined behavior. In c++ only up to one member of a `union` is active at any time. Only a `union`'s active member can be read from. Assigning to a `union` member makes it active and makes all other members inactive. For example, if you assign a value to `identity.data` it's undefined behavior to try to read from `identity.axis` until you assign a value to `identity.axis`, after which you can no longer read from `identity.data`. This is different from how it works in c.

By calling `void Matrix3::setRotateX(float radians)` you assign values to the `union`'s `xAxis`, `yAxis` and `zAxis` members, making the `struct` component of the `union` active. Then, when you multiply `m2` with `m3` you call `Matrix3 Matrix3::operator * (const Matrix3& other) const` which reads from the `union`'s `data` member which is not active, which leads to undefined behavior.

The easiest solution would likely to be to dispose of the `union` all together and use only one of the representations.

Comment: _"This is different from how it works in c."_ I am not certain, but is this actually true? I thought it was UB in C too, just peeps got away with it due to mainstream compiler behaviours (and/or just everybody _thought_ it was safe due to myths and legends).

Comment: [Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c#comment26826326_2313676) we can call it valid in all standard versions of C as long as we accept that a DR from 2004 applies retroactively (which is officially true but something I've never really acknowledged in practice to be quite honest)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit At least in C11. There is [this footnote](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95) in this C11 standard draft.