# Strange output when using union type members

Tags: c, types, unions

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

union U{
    int x;
    char y;
};

int main()
{
    union U u1;
    u1.x = 258;
    u1.y = '0';
    printf("%d%d",u1.x,u1.y);
    return 0;
}
```

Strangely, the output is `30448`.

Can someone please explain how this happens?

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: It's only portable to read the last member of a union that was assigned.

Comment: Note too that `'0'` is not the same thing as `0`, which may be a factor in your confusion.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, but *something* happened. The `258` is hex `102` so after writing that the four bytes contained `02 01 00 00` (little-endian). You then overwrote the first byte with `'0'` which is hex `30`. So the four bytes are now `30 01 00 00` and hex `130` is decimal `304`. But because you did not output a space, the next value hex `30` decimal `48` was run in to it, and the output `304 48` is shown as `30448`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of Unions in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 3):

You maybe missunderstanding the purpose of a `union`. It is meant to store only one variable at a time, but this variable can have multiple types. The last variable stored will overwrite the previous.

In your case `u1.y` (which is `'0'`, it's relevant to remind that the 1 byte ASCII decimal representation for `'0'` is `48`), is the last value stored, this corresponds to last 2 digits of your output as you print `'0'` by its ASCII decimal representation.

As for the first part of the output, note that you overwrite  the `int` variable `258`, which is presumably 4 bytes (but for the sake of explanation I will assume it's 2 bytes) with the 1 byte wide `char` variable `48`.

The binary value for `258` (assuming 2 bytes wide `int`) is:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|

|   2nd byte    |   1st byte    |
```

The binary value for `48` (1 byte wide `char` variable) is:

```
| | | | | | | | |0|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|

                |   1st byte    |
```

When you overwrite the two byte union variable with a one byte variable only the 8 least significant bits(least significant byte) will be overwritten, so you'll end up with:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|
| | | | | | | | |0|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|

|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|
```

And this is the binary representation of `304`.

So yor code first prints the 2 bytes wide (for the sake of the examle) `int` `304` and next the 1 byte wide `int` `48` (the ASCII `int` representation of `'0'`), hence the output `30448`.

Note that this behavior is ***not*** undefined.

[ISO/IEC 9899:2017 N2176](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

> #### § 6.5.2.3
>
> <sup>**97)**</sup> ***If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type** as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation.*
>
> #### § 6.2.6.2
>
> **6** - *When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values.<sup>51)</sup> The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.*
>
> **7** - ***When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.***

For confirmation you can use:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void*)&u1.x, (void*)&u1.y);
```

This will print the memory address of both `u1.x` and `u1.y` and you will not be shocked to find that they are the same.

Comment: For 2 **or more** byte **little-endian** `int`. For people unaware of computers other than consumer desktops and laptops and similar, 4-byte LE is the most likely by far.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yours is an interesting comment and true too. In any case I'm not trying to accurately portray byte ordering, just a comprehensible visualization of the sequence of events that leads to the output, regardless of endianness, which I believe could confuse the OP further.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot *read* a member of a union other than the one last *written* into

```
#include<stdio.h>
union U{
int x;
char y;
};

int main()
{
    union U u1;
    u1.x = 258; // write into member x: OK
    u1.y = '0'; // write into member y: OK
    printf("%d%d",u1.x,u1.y); // read both member x and y: WRONG
                              // can only read member y
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no rule in the C standard against reading a union member other than the last one modified, C 2018 6.5.2.3 says that reading a member produces the value of the named member, and note 99 explains the appropriate part of the object representation is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type.

Comment: [C11 J.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.1) -- **portability issues** -- The values of bytes that correspond to union members other than the one last stored into [is unspecified]. And there are a [few](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note46) [footnotes](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95) [throughout](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p16) the Standard that make the issue kinda murky @EricPostpischil

Comment: Yes, it is not portable. But you can do it. And the resulting behavior is specified: The appropriate bytes of the union are reinterpreted as the new type. The statement “You cannot *read* a member of a union other than the last one *written* into” is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil+ technically writing a text stream (which stdout is) with the last or only (pseudo)line not terminated by `\n` is impl-def and arguably may be undefined :-}