# How do I cast a float pointer to a uint8_t pointer in Metal Shader Language?

Tags: c, pointers, metal, uint8t

I am trying to write the following C code in Metal Shading Language inside of a `kernel void` function:

```
float f = 2.1;
uint8_t byteArray[sizeof(f)];
for (int a = 0; a < sizeof(f); a++) {
    byteArray[a] = ((uint8_t*)&f)[a];
}
```

The code is supposed to get a byte array of the float value. When I try to write the same code in Metal Shader Language, I get the following build-time error:

> Pointer type must have explicit address space qualifier

I understand that Metal restricts the use of pointers and requires that arguments to a kernel function are provided with an explicit address space attribute such as `device`, `constant`, etc. How would I perform the type-cast in Metal Shading Language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't C++, so you have to do it the other way.

You can't use unions or `reinterpret_cast` in MSL properly.

Instead, there's a type for a vector of 4 `uint8_t`s, it's `uchar4`.

To do what you are trying to do, you would write it something like this.

```
float f = 2.1;
uchar4 ff = as_type<uchar4>(f);
```

Refer to the MSL [spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), section 2.19 Type Conversions and Re-interpreting data.

As for address space qualifiers:

Every pointer in Metal Shading Language has an address qualifier. It can be a `device`, `constant`, `thread`, `threadgroup` and others. Refer to Chapter 4 in the spec.

These address qualifiers come from the fact that there are different memory spaces. You can read more about them in the document above.

Since `f` is local variable, it's in `thread` space, so your `uint8_t` pointer would have a type of `thread uint8_t*` and not just `uint8_t`.

So you could probably do it like this:

```
float f = 2.1;
thread uint8_t* ff = (thread uint8_t*)&f;
```

But I think the `as_type` approach is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about `metal` specifically, but in ordinary C, you'd want to put `f` and `byteArray` inside a `union`

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union float_byte {
    float f;
    uint8_t byteArray[sizeof(float)];
};

union float_byte u;

void
dotest(float f)
{

    u.f = f;

    printf("%.6f",u.f);
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(u.byteArray);  ++idx)
        printf(" %2.2X",u.byteArray[idx]);
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(2.1);
    dotest(7.6328);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
2.100000 66 66 06 40
7.632800 E6 3F F4 40
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> even today, isn't it still technically UB to read a union member that wasn't the last one written to? Although, it sounds like this is widely supported now with implementation-defined behavior. One of many related questions: stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/… – yano

No, it's *not* UB for a number of reasons.

It *might* be "implementation defined" behavior, but *only* because of the CPU/processor endianness re. the format of a [32 bit] `float` in memory, if we wished to interpret the bytes in `byteArray`

But, AFAICT, that doesn't affect OP's issue since the point was just to get a byte buffer [for binary/serialization of the data?].

If one wanted to interpret the data (e.g. designing a DIY F.P. S/W implementation), then the format and endianness of the `float` would have to be known. This is [probably] IEEE 784 format, and the processor endianness.

But, using the `union` to *just* get a byte pointer, there is no issue. It's *not* even "implementation defined" behavior.

It's just about the same as:

```
float my_f = f;
uint8_t *byteArray = (uint8_t *) &my_f;
```

And, it works because it *has* to work.

Also, the `union` [as used here] is a common idiom, dating back to the 1970's so it *has* to be supported.

Also, it just *works* [because it has to by design].

If we had:

```
void
funcA(float f)
{

    u.f = f;
}

void
funcB(void)
{
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < sizeof(u.byteArray);  ++idx)
        printf(" %2.2X",u.byteArray[idx]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

For fun, assume `funcA` and `funcB` are in separate `.c` files. When `funcA` is called it changes the memory of `u` [in a predictable way].

Nothing in between changes the layout of `u`.

Then, we call `funcB`. The layout of the bytes in `byteArray` will be the same/predictable data.

This is similar to and works the same way as writing the `float` to a file as *binary* data:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int fd;

void
writefloat(float f)
{
    float my_f = f;

    write(fd,&my_f,sizeof(float));
}

void
writefloat2(float f)
{

    write(fd,&f,sizeof(float));
}

void
writefloat3(float f)
{

    write(fd,&f,sizeof(f));
}
```

Perhaps this would be easier to see if we used `uint32_t` instead of `float`. We could do an endian test. [Note: this is crude and doesn't account for oddball endianness like pdp11/vax]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union uint_byte {
    uint32_t i;
    uint8_t b[sizeof(uint32_t)];
};

union uint_byte u;

int
main(void)
{

    u.i = 0x01020304;
    if (u.b[0] == 0x04)
        printf("cpu is little-endian\n");
    else
        printf("cpu is big-endian\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even today, isn't it still technically UB to read a union member that wasn't the last one written to? Although, it sounds like this is widely supported now with implementation-defined behavior. One of many related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c

Comment: @yano I've added an update to my answer to address your concerns

Answer (score -1):

In c++ (20) you have [`bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).
In the section 'Notes' you will see, that it is simply implemented as a call to `memcpy`.

So, in order to avoid 'undefined behaviour' and to be safe (besides of all the previous, it is also the fastest), just do:

```
memcpy(byteArray, &f, sizeof f); //size of byteArray must be at least: sizeof f
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works in C++, not in Metal.