# How do I reinterpret an unsigned long (DWORD) as a signed long in C++?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, unsigned-integer

I want to reinterpret an `unsigned long` (actually, a `DWORD`) as a `signed long`. I tried:

```
DWORD x;
long y = reinterpret_cast<signed long>(x);
```

However, VC++2010 intellisense tells me "Invalid type conversion". Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205353/why-doesnt-this-reinterpret-cast-compile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476182/which-cast-to-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try static_cast instead.  VC generates an error if you try an excessively permissive cast (like using reinterpret_cast when static_cast or const_cast will suffice).

There are 5 types of casts in C++, each of which allows you to do more (grants more permissions).   The least permissive casts are const casts (`const_cast<int>(<const int>)`) which allow you to change the const modifier.  There are static casts (`static_cast<int>)(<short>)`) which allow you to perform type safe coersions (cast base to derived, for example).There are dynamic casts (`dynamic_cast<derived_type>(base_type)` that allow you to cast from one type to another *if* there is a legal conversion between the two (and that return null if there is no conversion).  Finally, there are casts that allow conversion between unrelated types - reinterpret_cast `reinterpret_cast<int>(<void *>)` and C style cast `(int)<void *>`.

I don't have a good way of describing these different types of casts, so I describe them as "more permissive" because each of them allows you to do more.

VC warns you if you are using a reinterpret cast when one of the other cast types would be more appropriate to achieve your goal.   C style casts don't have a similar warning for backwards compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean by *"excessively permissive"*?

Comment: there's slight mistake in your second paragraph where you say (change a to be ?) it just trails off.

Comment: Good explanation, not too long and painful. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `reinterpret_cast` to convert unsigned type into a signed one, `static_cast` will do.

Comment: is that why it says invalid type conversion?

Comment: @0A0D: Standard explicitly names what you can use `reinterpret_cast` on, integral type to an integral type is not part of that list.

Comment: looking into it again, you can reinterpret_cast short to int, so why is that OK and not unsigned long to signed long? Is it because it is long-to-long, instead of long-to-int, for instance?

Comment: @0A0D: I don't know, really. You should ask someone more familiar with the standardese.