# Struct inheritance causing non-aggregate type error on static initialization

Tags: c++, struct

I currently have the following:

```
struct MsgHeader_t
{
    int   a;
    float b;
};
```

which initializes a default const as

```
const MsgHeader_t default = { 0, 0.0f };
```

which was working fine.  Now I have to extend it and it MUST inherit from another struct.  So now I have.

```
struct MsgId_t
{
    unsigned int id;
};

struct MsgHeader_t : public MsgId_t
{
    int   a;
    float b;
};
```

But now when I try to initialize that default const (`const MsgHeader_t aMessage = { 0, 0, 0.0f };`)
I get

`error: braces around initializer for non-aggregate type 'const MsgHeader_t'`

Comment: `MsgHeader_t` is POD but no longer an aggregate type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808357/brace-initialization-for-inherited-pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have inheritance, then your class can no longer be an aggregate type. From this [Draft C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (bold italics mine):

> **8.5.1 Aggregates**
>
> <sup>1</sup> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), ***no base classes*** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

Comment: I made be a little dense in my reading but does that mean I should be able to provide a ctor for it and all should be good?  Also, what is a POD?

Comment: POD = "Plain Old Data." Yes, a constructor would work, and this could use 'brace' initialization for the base class. Also, it's not for me to assess your [specific gravity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=YNyVXuPQEZGxU8j4lagI&q=specific+gravity&oq=specific+gravity&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoFCAAQgwFKJwgXEiMwZzgzZzk1ZzY2ZzgwZzExM2c2NWc1NWc2NGc3MGc3Nmc3MUobCBgSFzBnMWcxZzFnMWcxZzFnMWcxZzFnNWcyUPsFWO4dYIAlaABwAHgAgAFliAHaCJIBBDE1LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab).

Comment: Very funny.  Thanks for making me look things up :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that since C++17, you might do, as you expect:

- `const MsgHeader_t aMessage = { 0, 0, 0.0f };`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8kUe4B)
- or more properly `const MsgHeader_t aMessage = { {0}, 0, 0.0f };`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zvd4Cm)

Comment: I wish.  Unfortunately I'm in C++89.

Comment: That the kind of info which should be in question, IMO.